# Hi, I have just started learning R and would like to add curve to the function

Tags: r, function, curve

I have just started learning R  and would like to add curve to the function.
But receiving "Error in logistic(x, c(0.05, 3)) : object 't_0' not found"

```
logistic<-function(t,theta=c(b,t_0)) {
return((exp(b*(t-t_0))/(1+exp(b*(t-t_0))))) #function
}  
x<-c(-30:30)
curve(logistic(x,c(0.05,3)),from=-30, to=30, add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an vector to a function like that in R. You can pass a vector but use `[]` indexes to access their elements:

```
logistic<-function(t,theta=c(b,t_0)) {
  return((exp(theta[1]*(t-theta[2]))/(1+exp(theta[1]*(t-theta[2]))))) #function
}
```

Or you can pass each element as a different argument:

```
logistic<-function(t, b, t_0) {
  return((exp(b*(t-t_0))/(1+exp(b*(t-t_0))))) #function
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Took me 5 hours:)

Comment: If it helped, please accept the answer to mark the post as solved :)